# Applying group-specific minimum values by factor level in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (45k rows) that contains a categorical variable of interest with ~50 factor levels. Each observation is associated with a date. For each factor level I would like to identify the earliest date associated with the factor level, and then I would like to assign each observation the corresponding Group-specific earliest date under the column name `df$Reference_date`. I can do this manually like so (Reprex with toy dataset):

```
# Create dataframe
df<-
  data.frame(
    Group=c(
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
      ),
    Date=as.Date(
      c(
        "2010-07-06",
        "2008-03-28",
        "2009-12-02",
        "2009-06-05",
        "2010-05-07",
        "2009-06-15"
        )
      )
    )

# Calculate Group-specific minimum values
min(
  subset(
    df,
    Group=="A"
  )$Date
)

min(
  subset(
    df,
    Group=="B"
  )$Date
)

min(
  subset(
    df,
    Group=="C"
  )$Date
)

# Assign reference dates (based on previous step)
df$Reference_date[df$Group=="A"]="2009-06-05"
df$Reference_date[df$Group=="B"]="2008-03-28"
df$Reference_date[df$Group=="C"]="2009-06-15"

df$Reference_date<-
  as.Date(
    df$Reference_date
  )
```

However, this is time-consuming in the first instance, and would cause problems later down the line if I were to add more factor levels. I am sure that there must be some sort of `apply()` function that I can use to split, process, and merge my dataframe but I can't quite work it out. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try using dplyr - `df %>% mutate(Reference_date = min(Date), .by = Group)` or if you have an older version of dplyr: `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Reference_date = min(Date))`

Comment: See linked post, in base R, use ave.